"Exponent" terminology in the hypergeometric differential equation
The hypergeometric differential equation
$$\frac {d^2 f} {d z^2}+ \left( {\frac {1 - \alpha - \alpha'} {z - a} + \frac {1 - \beta - \beta'} {z - b} + \frac {1 - \gamma - \gamma'} {z - c} } \right) \frac {d f} {d z} +\left(\frac{\alpha \alpha^{\prime}(a-b)(a-c)}{z-a}+\frac{\beta \beta^{\prime}(b-c)(b-a)}{z-b}+\frac{\gamma \gamma^{\prime}(c-a)(c-b)}{z-c}\right) \frac{f}{(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)} = 0$$
contains the constants $\alpha, \alpha', \beta, \beta', \gamma, \gamma'$.
I have often heard said constants referred to as "exponents" of the hypergeometric differential equation.
What exactly does this mean? I think I have gathered that near the point $z=a$, as the equation is a second-order differential equation, the two solutions should behave like $e^{\alpha}$, $e^{\alpha'}$, similarly at $b, c$, but I may be misunderstanding this.
What is the correct interpretation of the term "exponent", here to describe these quantities? How can we show these exponents arise?

What you call "hypergeometric differential equation" is in fact Riemann's differential equation. You will find the answer to your question in the link.
